# ActiveAdmin and Rails 4 creating a model resource broke my project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I was following the instructions at http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/0-installation.html#gemfile under the heading Register your models with Active Admin. Before adding the resource of Post I was able to start my server just fine. Once I added the resource of Post, it would no longer start. It was giving me an error about the I18n.config.enforce_available_locales needing to be set to false to prevent the error message. I found another Stack Overflow post which said to set this to false in the application.rb file. After doing this the message no longer shows in my Terminal interface, but the servers don't start.

Now I am getting the following output in Terminal when I run $ rails server

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ruby-review/app/admin/post.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Post (NameError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:179:in `load'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:171:in `block in load!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:171:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:171:in `load!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:195:in `routes'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-9ca081f47ab4/lib/active_admin.rb:80:in `routes'
from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ruby-review/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `instance_exec'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `eval_block'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:319:in `draw'
from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ruby-review/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ruby-review/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ruby-review/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ruby-review/config.ru:in `new'
from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ruby-review/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

How to I initialize the Constant of Post?

My apologies if these errors seem obvious to some. I am still new to rails.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a `Post` model. Do this:

```
$ rails g model Post
$ rake db:migrate
```